# Unknown files in postgres server

Tags: postgresql, config

I have a server for postgres only but now it seems the storage going to be full on the /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/base

Inside the directory, there's a lot of data which I can't read.

Can I just delete the files? Or is it important?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files contain your data and are a vital part for a correctly working Postgres server.

Do **NOT** delete them.

Do not even touch them if you care about your data.

If you want to get more information about what the files are, please see the chapter [Database File Layout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html) in th emanual.

Comment: So does that mean the more data that I input in my DB, the more files it will have in the server as well?

Comment: Yes, quoting from the manual which @a_horse_with_no_name links to above: "Each table and index is stored in a separate file", "When a table or index exceeds 1 GB, it is divided into gigabyte-sized segments". Read the linked manual if you want to know more about the structure and files.

Comment: But my storage is going to be full and this takes a lot of space. Any recommendation on how I can optimize the space?

Comment: @devilHunter: that's simple: don't insert that much data into your tables. The size of those files only depends on the size of the data you insert into your tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not possible to not insert data to my table since it's a production DB.. Im new to postgres so I dunno whether there is other option. Hard Disk full, it will affect the service.

Comment: @devilHunter: if you need that data, you will have to buy a bigger hard disk. There is no other solution.